# Width and Height must be non-zero when scaling image for JPanel

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel

I am trying to scale an image to fit within a JPanel in my GUI. Whenever I create a new instance of `ImagePanel` in my JFrame, I get an exception because the width and the height are both 0. However, I overrode `getPreferredSize()` so it seems like the width and height should be non-zero values.

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

private Image image;

public ImagePanel() {
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/opening.jpg"));
        image = scaleImage(image);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
}

public void setImage(Image i) {
    image = scaleImage(i);
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(500, 500);
}

public Image scaleImage(Image i) {
    return i.getScaledInstance(getWidth(), getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
}
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (0) and height (0) must be non-zero
at java.awt.image.ReplicateScaleFilter.<init>(ReplicateScaleFilter.java:102)
at java.awt.image.AreaAveragingScaleFilter.<init>(AreaAveragingScaleFilter.java:77)
at java.awt.Image.getScaledInstance(Image.java:172)
at ImagePanel.scaleImage(ImagePanel.java:40)
at ImagePanel.<init>(ImagePanel.java:18)
at GUIFrame.<init>(GUIFrame.java:44)
at main.main(main.java:6)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Comment: Can you show the stack trace?

Comment: @MordechayS yes, I just added the stack trace

Comment: `getPreferredSize()` is a request, not a guarantee. When you first create the `JPanel`, it's not part of a component hierarchy yet, so it hasn't had an opportunity to be sized. You'll need to call `scaleImage` sometime after the panel has been added to a parent container and laid out. Or you could use the preferred size as the arguments rather than the actual size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A component doesn't have a size until the panel is displayed in a visible GUI.

So the solution is to do the scaling of your image dynamically in the `paintComponent(...)` method.

Note you can do this with the `drawImage(...)` method directly. Read the API there is a method that allows you to specify the width/height of the image as you paint the image.

Answer (score 0):

From `Oracle`'s [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html):

> "The `pack()` method sizes the frame **so that all its contents are at or**
>   **above their preferred sizes**..."

So, until you call `pack()` on your containing `JFrame` - your components won't have any size except the default one - which is **zero**.

See these answers for more information:

- [Width and Height Set To Zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336262/why-cant-i-access-my-panels-getwidth-and-getheight-functions).
- [What does pack do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22982295/what-does-pack-do)